# How to account for variable group sizes in linear model?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, mixed-models, random-effects

Example: My linear model shows that plant richness increases with latitude. However, the number of individuals surveyed in each sampling site also increases with latitude. Can I include the number of individuals per sampling site as a random effect in a linear mixed model?